# Dual-booting my system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu and booting the same Windows OS into a VM while running Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, virtualization

0 down vote favorite
1

So essentially I would like to be able to physically boot from either W7 or Linux on start-up, but I would rather remove the hassle of having to shut down everything I'm doing in Linux and wait for Windows to boot up in order to use Windows-only applications.

I googled the topic extensively (I think...) and couldn't really find an informative and knowledgeable answer... I would very much appreciate anyone's input on this.

Someone on a forum mentioned something about the registry and drivers having issues as the VM runs on abstracted hardware, but I'm not sure if there are ways to get around or patch that.

Before anyone asks, the reason I wish to do this is so that I could primarily use Linux and just run a Windows 7 VM seamlessly over it, but I also want to be able to boot directly into the Windows partition for more hardware-intensive applications like gaming and graphic design.

I really appreciate anyone's advice on the matter!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly, you want the actual windows installation to be available as  your vm. Or else constantly sync  all changes with your vm install on ubuntu. If that is the case, then the answer is it cannot be done. This would envolve writing any changes to the vmware environment to the base windows installation. Basic os architecture will not allow that.

The only  solution I can think of is to keep all your user files in your windows  and vm synced with a cloud syncing solution. Something like Ubuntu One or Dropbox. In that way, changed files and documents will be available in both windows native as in windows vm

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174581/is-there-any-way-to-boot-windows-7-partition-in-virtual-machine), it is possible, but very difficult to do and prone to blue screen errors in Windows.

My reading of the Win 7 license allows you to use your copy in either a physical install or in a virtual machine, as long as it's one at a time. One solution is to create a normal physical dual-boot and then install Windows to a virtual machine in Ubuntu. It's not quite as convenient since you will need to install software and windows updates twice; then again, avoiding blue screens and having Windows continue to work is a big plus.

You can use either your Windows system restore disk, if you have one, to install the VM, or you can find a Windows 7 iso and use your exisiting product key. Using the first method, your Windows VM should activate without problem. After using this second method, activation may fail; but you can then use the option to place an automated phone call to Microsoft and receive an activation key.