# how to add boot media for VM to boot Windows 7?

Tags: boot, virtualbox, windows-7, iso

I have created my 1st Virtual Box machine after turning on Virtualization in my BIOS and it went immediately down because I did not have a Windows 7 boot image set for it to boot from. I have 3 original Win 7 Installation disks so I need to know how to put 1 on a flash as an ISO and be able to feed the data to the virtual machine that I want to run.

Alternatively, there are many referenced for virtual Linux machines, how do I get one and make it work?

My desire is to create my first working VM. From here I go to try more powerful VM stuff from the real world. Will do heavy collaboration with experienced persons, I am a Linux advanced newbie with heavy experience in hdwe and software. Running 32GB server on AMD Phenom II 6 core with 3 laptop/workstations. SSDs, SSHDs and HDs total storage over 20TB.

Thanks 
DL

Comment: Try this [OP](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174581/is-there-any-way-to-boot-windows-7-partition-in-virtual-machine/174582#174582)

Comment: Let me understand you, 1) create a VirtualBox with Windows 7 hardware configs, 2) Create an `Windows ISO` that this Virtualbox will use to run as a guest system in an Ubuntu host ?

Comment: Yes George, I have downloaded the virtualbox system, got it to create a VM test base, dealt with not having Virtualization enabled in the BIOS, fixed that and now have the system telling me that I do not have a boot image/ISO of Windows 7 set to boot. I am now going to google how to load a Windows 7 bootable ISO. I am sure to find that but I also want to know how to load it so that the Virtual box has access to it to boot it.

Comment: That's easy you either add it from settings or at boot. let me try to install one now and give u the info!

Answer (score 0):

Lets see how we can do this:

1. Download `ISO` image and have the *activation key* handy
2. Settings in VirtualBox:

   a. Name and Operating System:

   ```
   Name: Any name you like
   Type: Microsoft Windows
   Version: Windows 7 (64bits)
   ```

   b. Memory Size: `min 4000MB`

   c. Hard disk select:

   ```
   Create a virtual hard disk now
   ```

   d. Hard disk file type select:

   ```
   VDI( Virtualbox Disk Image)
   ```

   e. Storage on physical hard disk

   ```
   Dynamically allocated
   ```

   f. File location and size:

   ```
   min say: 80GB
   ```
3. After Creation select the `win 7 VM` in the Virtualbox window and click on `settings` this will take you into the various options for the VM:

[image]

4. Select `Storage`, here click or select the optical disk drive which should be empty and to the right where you have optical drive click and go to where you Windows & ISO image is located:

[image]

From here on it should install and ask for the usual windows parameters and what not.

**Note:**

Windows acts greedily towards hardware so make sure no other process that uses your hardware intensely is running.

And guest additions can also be used to directly communicate between guest and host systems.

Comment: Hello George, this all looks just GREAT! but I have a problem using Inet here. I am in a country that taxes Inet use like CRAZY so I have such limited Inet download capacity that it just sucks! The billionaires here saw how Carlos Slim made his billions and they are following suit. I do have my Win 7 Pro DVD that I purchased directly from MS but that does me little good as it is all a big conglomeration set up files. I have looked at the MS site & can download but not only is it prohibitive in price, it takes 4-8 hours. It took 6 hours to download the Ubuntu Desktop Ed and that is only 1.47GB.

Comment: Sorry to hear that try this [article](http://www.howtogeek.com/228886/how-to-create-iso-files-from-discs-on-windows-mac-and-linux/) on how to convert __dvd to ISO file__ so you can use it in the VM

Comment: Hi George, by playing lots of games, I did get an ISO of Win 7 but debatable that it is bootable, also got a complete setup on the same USB flash drive with boot. Used my Win7Pro install disks and ImgBurn, got burned badly by Burnaware, shut down my whole system hard. Will test tomorrow. Thanks much, it is late here in SE Asia.

Comment: Sure let me know how it goes!

Comment: Hello to the wonderful George and all at AskUbuntu, I am now having to go downstairs(live on the 2nd floor in a big highrise) to see about Cable Internet and do 200 pushups and 60 pullups(fitness nut) and then be right back. I have all the items ready to test what you have recommended, having some thoughts about loading the OS' onto the disk so I can get access to either set; the full setup or the full but not bootable ISO. Do NOT know how that will go??? Last, You are just simply wonderful, thank you. DL

Comment: Well you are in all our prayers hope it goes smoothly !

Comment: I have Win 7 Pro installing as I write this. All is well. For the benefit of others: If you get a Windows ISO, the system will start it for you. Just follow the install of the help.ubuntu.com/community/virtualbox/FirstVM  it is great! Thanks George and hope this helps others, always glad to help.

Comment: To George and all, I added a VB for Linux Mint with Cinnamon after I could not get the ISO to load directly onto my server. I was really let down by Mint on the first install but as it was able to get downloads, it turned out really beautiful with a better desktop than Ubuntu, personal opinion of course, things are out where you can work with them rather than stuck in a fast line. I am going to load all the top Linux OS' so that I can gain more depth but have to wait 2 weeks to get HS Internet with unlimited traffic 20MBS. Then will have my My Cloud online and storage and goodies galore. DL

Answer (score 0):

Use imgburn to create a Windows ISO then move the ISO to a flash drive. then point the virtual CD to the ISO on the flash drive for virtual Box. It will use it when you click the green start arrow up at the top of the Vbox window. Be sure to have your Win Activation Key.